# Does Fish have a "magic space"?

Tags: shell, fish

I gather that bash has a "magic space" function, where if I do e.g. `sudo !!<space>` it will blow in `sudo ./my_last_command`. Does something similar exist in fish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the FAQ in the source (I can't find any documentation online):

> Why doesn't history
>   substitution ("!$" etc.) work?
>
> Because history substitution is an
>   awkward interface that was invented
>   before interactive line editing was
>   even possible.  Fish drops it in favor
>   of perfecting the interactive history
>   recall interface.  Switching requires
>   a small change of habits: if you want
>   to modify an old line/word, first
>   recall it, then edit.  E.g. don't type
>   "sudo !!" - first press Up, then Home,
>   then type "sudo ".

Comment: That's hilarious. The only reason I use `sudo !!` is because it's faster and more convenient than the "*interactive*" way.

Comment: yep, not so easy to script an up cursor key press.